# Store value from SELECT statement into variable on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to select value from the system object,synonyms and then store into `@variable`. Then I can select data from `@variable` without caring the server.
However it keeps saying that I need to declare scalar variable. Can anyone help?

```
DECLARE @variable NVARCHAR(100)

SELECT @variable = name 
FROM sys.synonyms 
WHERE base_object_name = '[ABC].[dbo].[tblABC]'

SELECT * FROM @variable
```

Comment: `select @variable` but You get last value of Name

Comment: If your goal is to write a sql statement that interprets the value of your variable as an actual object (table or view in this case), you can't to it directly. It requires dynamic sql - which is a rather advanced skill. Search the internet if that is your goal. TBH, it seems to me that you are defeating the entire purpose for defining and using synonyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query selects all names and successively stores them in the variable, meaning that each name overwrites the previously stored name, so only the last selected name is available in the variable when the SELECT statement terminates. If you want a variable that you can query like a temporary table, you will have to declare a table variable and insert the names into that "table", afterwards you can run a select statement against that variable:

```
Declare @variable table (name nvarchar(128));

INSERT INTO @variable (name)
SELECT name 
FROM  sys.synonyms 
where base_object_name = '[ABC].[dbo].[tblABC]';

select * from @variable;
```

But: Also on this query, the server will "care".

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to return only one value to the variable. In this way:

```
Declare @variable nvarchar(100)

@variable = (SELECT TOP(1) name -- getting only one registry
    FROM  sys.synonyms where base_object_name = 
    '[ABC].[dbo].[tblABC]')

select @variable
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do next :

```
declare @names table ( name nvarchar(100 ) );

insert @names(name)
select name 
FROM sys.synonyms 
where base_object_name = '[ABC].[dbo].[tblABC]'; 

select * from @names
```